# Webservice - Use username in function after login

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm creating a web service with user authentication via HTTP. The authentication is done in @auth.get_password:

```
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

@auth.get_password
def getPassword(user):
   if user == 'dummy':
       return password
   else:
       return None
```

Now I want to create a function where I can also use this given username, e.g. for changing user's password:

```
# Change password
@app.route('/users/change_password/', methods=['PUT'])
@auth.login_required
def changeUserPassword(user):
    return user + ", You want to change your password"
```

But there is no "user" variable. How can I pass the "user" to the function `changeUserPassword()` ? I do not want to start a session or something because I'm trying to build a RESTful web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `flask-httpauth`, you can use [`auth.username()`](http://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#flask_httpauth.HTTPBasicAuth.username) to get the current user

```
@app.route('/users/change_password/', methods=['PUT'])
@auth.login_required
def changeUserPassword(user):
    return auth.username() + ", You want to change your password"
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Unfortunately I am not using `flask.ext.login` so I do not have a login_manager, that seems to be required by `current_user`

Comment: @zarathustra I missed you were using `httpauth`. I've edited the answer